# Insert before table with span using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Here's my code:

```
<td valign="top">
 <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td valign="top">
     <span itemprop="testx"></span>
    </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</td>
```

I need to insert text here

```
<td valign="top">
 *NEW TEXT HERE*
 <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td valign="top">
     <span itemprop="testx"></span>
    </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</td>
```

I've tried this:

```
jQuery("span[itemprop$='testx']").parents('table').before("NEW TEXT");
```

But I have many other tables in the page and this puts it way at the top. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `:first` selector :

```
$("span[itemprop$='testx']").parents('table:first').before("NEW TEXT");
```

Answer (score 1):

`parents` selects all the matching parent elements of the selected element, you can use `closest` method.

```
$("span[itemprop='testx']").closest('table').before("NEW TEXT");
```

Answer (score 0):

set for table some id or class and then just replace with ("#table") or (".table")